# Open win form on click of url within a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, html, windows, web-controls

I have a Windows app where i use webbrowser control to show html text.
the problem is that i have some links in that html that i need them to open another win forms when user clicks them.

What I am suppose to write in the link

```
<a href:????> click to show another win form</a>
```

or there is another method.please help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What you are looking for is called the `ObjectForScripting` property of the `WebBrowser` control. Look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info and an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute methods in your windows app by doing the following:
First add permission, so add this above public class Form1 : Form

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

Second you need to register your webbrowser control to have access to call your form functions, so add this to the Form_Load event

```
this.WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

Then you can create a Sub in your Main form. The sub MUST be Public.

```
public void doOpenForm()
{
    //your code to open the form here
}
```

And in your HTML, do this:

```
<a href='' onclick='window.external.doOpenForm()'> click to show another win form</a>
```

Comment: True, it's pretty easily translated to C#...the concepts are the same, just different sytax